# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'author' for one to many

Tags: python, one-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

So, im trying to reference a users post ? and i keep getting this error

**error**

```
>>> from app import db, models
>>> u = models.User.query.get(2)
>>> p = models.Post(title='barn owl', body='thompson', author=u)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'author'
```

I'm trying to reference posts by users.

**Models.py**

```
from app import app, db, bcrypt, slugify, flask_whooshalchemy, JWT, jwt_required, current_identity, safe_str_cmp
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, DateTime, func
from app import (TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer
                          as Serializer, BadSignature, SignatureExpired)

import datetime


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password, 9)
    
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True
    
    def is_active(self):
        return True
        
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False
        
    def get_id(self):
        return  (self.id)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

    
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
            
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,  primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    # slug = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, nullable=True)
    
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
                    
    def __init__(self, title, body):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body

        # self.slug = slugify(title).lower()
```

I'm pretty confused, i have been referencing the [flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) im not really having success, does anyone have any suggestions, im about to go nuts

Comment: Delete the `author` parameter in `p = models.Post(title='barn owl', body='thompson', author=u)`

Comment: that works, but it does not reference the users post, you know what i mean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or just add author as a relationship and add author as a parameter to the `__init__` method

```
# inside Post definition
author = db.relationship("User")

def __init__(self,title,body,author):
    self.author = author
```

Comment: let me give this a shot kyle

Comment: it gave me this

sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Error creating backref 'author' on relationship 'User.posts': property of that name exists on mapper 'Mapper|Post|posts'

Comment: Remove the posts line from the User class, and to continue using User.posts, just add backref="posts" in the author relationship

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKS, now i have to figure out to use this in the views.py file and then the JINJA FILE, thanks soo freakking much made my day

Comment: when i do posts = u.posts.all() i get AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'u'

u = models.User.query.get(2) by the way

Comment: @OwlMan `author = db.relationship("User",backref=db.backref("posts",lazy="dynamic"))`  that should fix it

Comment: just wanted to say thankyou, im a little bit upset that flask don't have enough documentation or tutorials to learn this shit from. But i guess the only real way to learn is through hours of debugging

Comment: flask has excellent docs in my opinion, I think the issue your having is based on flask's insistence that it is a  "minimal web framework", meaning it only includes parts that are "required" when writing web apps, unfortunately something not included in the minimal architecture is a way to map database models to classes, i.e.: an ORM, one was not included so you can choose whatever ORM you would like, sqlalchemy and peewee are 2 more popular ones. Here I think your issue is with the fact that there isn't much flask documentation on integrating sqlalchemy, but it's docs are pretty thorough.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is:

```
p = models.Post(title='barn owl', body='thompson', user_id=u.id)
#                                                  ^^^^^^^ ^ ^^
```

And as Kyle mentioned, add the `user_id` argument to the `__init__` of `Post`:

```
def __init__(self, title, body, user_id):
    ...
    self.body = body
    self.user_id = user_id
    ...
```

Because your post contains a `user_id`, not an `author`:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    ...
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    ...
```

and your user has an `id`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

Comment: it didn't work, i keep getting __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument

Comment: It's because he's defining `__init__` and isn't telling it to expect a parameter named author, it's being very clear

Comment: Ahh, thanks @KyleRoux - I was thinking in terms of django where you don't need the `__init__`. Will edit the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @bahrom In sqlalchemy the `__init__` isn't required, but if you do define it and you don't add `**kwargs` you need to explicitly define the keyword args, I believe djangos orm works the same way.

Comment: @Bahrom were you having the same struggles as well